# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:

Tags: java, string, double

I have a problem when trying to convert from a jformattedtextfield to a double. Im writing my program in java. Its my final school project, any help would be appreachieated.

my code:

```
String tal1;
    tal1 = jFormattedTextField1.getText();
    double nummer1 = Double.parseDouble(tal1);
```

Comment: Print out `tal1` to see what it is, then go read the Javadoc to understand the required format accepted by `Double.parseDouble`.

Comment: You are passing an empty string. I suggest you add a `println("tal1 = " + tal1)` before parsing it to confirm it.

Comment: You may have an empty string retrieved from the JFormattedTextField. I suggest putting the Double.parseDouble method in a try/catch block

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing from the code that you are using JFormattedTextField?

if so you need to get the value not the text.
this extract is from the java tutorials, modified it to use your variable names

```
((Number)jFormattedTextField1.getValue()).intValue();
```

Checkout these links for details on how to use that component.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#getValue()

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html

Hope these sites help

Comment: Was about to write the same. I take it you meant `doubleValue()` in this particular case ;)

Comment: oh yeah, nicely spotted :)